# Conversion of Date into string in java when storing in database

Tags: java, oracle10g, flex3, cairngorm

there is a value object processVO having date variable of string type in it( with getter & setter) .I am trying to populate it in in my DAO class in following way:-    PreparedStatement.setString(processVO.getDate);
It is giving me an error as:- 
cannot convert Date type into String.
//the value stored in processVO.getDate() is having date & time both i.e. "2-apr-2013 1:20 am"

Comment: simply use string in front end and back end.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be considered a good practice, but in case of simple retrieving the string you can use the toString() method on the processVO.getDate() like

```
processVO.getDate().toString()
```